# Split information from a database-column to Text and Numbers

Tags: c#, sql, linq, split

Im retriving data from a database displayed on a dropdownlist. The dropdown display the streetname along with the number of the house. An example from my data is: **"Streetname 44"**. Now when the data isretrived and displayed on the dropdown, I want to save the data into another table in the database, but this time i want the **"Streetname"** to be on the "street-column" and the **"44"** stored in the "number-column".
Im using LINQ to store my data and so far I have this:

```
         using (DB_Entities tt = new DB_Entities())
        {
            Address va = new Address();
            va.Street = ListItemStreet.SelectedItem; // I only want the Strings from the itemlist
            va.HouseNo = ListItemStreet.SelectedItem; // I only want the number from the itemlist

            tt.ValidateAddress.AddObject(va);
            tt.SaveChanges();

            if (tt != null)
            {
                AddError.Text = "Saved!";
            }
            else
            {
                AddError.Text = "Error";
            }
    }
```

**EDIT:** It's not a textbox but a Itemlist were the street is retrieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse like this:

```
string address = "Streetname 44";

var index = address.LastIndexOf(' ');

var houseNo = address.Substring(index + 1);
var streetName = address.Remove(index);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but how do i use the following code on ListboxStreet.SelectedValue ?

Comment: you can store ListboxStreet.SelectedValue in the address variable instead of using the string literal from the example.

Comment: Alright now im getting this error: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. On the tt.savechanges(); line